# Clickhouse protobuf output format

Tags: http-headers, protocol-buffers, clickhouse, dbeaver, clickhouse-client

I use [clickhouse server in docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server) with just 1 table and several rows in it. I can request all the data in default format with [clickhouse client](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/cli/) (over TCP) or with some GUI tool like DBeaver (over HTTP).

```
SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

Also I can [change format](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/) to something special:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table FORMAT Pretty;
```

I want to request data from clickhouse in protobuf format. Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table FORMAT Protobuf SETTINGS format_schema = 'proto_file:ProtoStructure';
```

I have the `proto_file.proto` in the same directory with clickhouse-client, so I can made TCP request throw it (successful).

But [I don't know data structure of TCP request](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/tcp/) to reproduce it in my program by myself. So I tried to execute the same request in HTTP (through DBeaver) to intercept request and reproduce it. Unfortunately I can't execute script in DBeaver properly, because it complains on `proto_file.proto` (`File not found`, I don't know where to place it to make it work). The only thing I known, that format is specified by `X-Clickhouse-Format` HTTP header, but I don't know and can't find any info about where in HTTP request I should place content of proto file.

So, the main question: Is there any examples of pure HTTP request to clickhouse for protobuf data output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SETTINGS format_schema = 'proto_file:ProtoStructure'` -- is the feature of `clickhouse-client` application. It's only possible with `clickhouse-client`.

`clickhouse-client` is the reach client. It queries data from `clickhouse-server` using TPC/native protocol and forms `Protobuf` by itself using the schema file.

`clickhouse-server` is also able to form `Protobuf` using .proto files (using HTTP and GRPC protocols). But in this case .proto files should be placed at the `clickhouse-server` node into `/var/lib/clickhouse/format_schemas/` folder.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings/#server_configuration_parameters-format_schema_path

---

for example I created .proto file

```
cat /var/lib/clickhouse/format_schemas/test.proto
syntax = "proto3";

message TestMessage {
  int64 id = 1;
  uint32 blockNo = 2;
  string val1 = 3;
  float  val2 = 4;
  uint32 val3 = 5;
};
```

made it available `chown clickhouse.clickhouse test.proto`

Now I can do this

```
curl -o out.protobuf 'localhost:8123/?format_schema=test:TestMessage&query=select+1+id+from+numbers(10)+format+Protobuf'
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is obvious. I already specified all this stuff in my question. I'm looking for the way of requesting data from the server in HTTP (the original recommended and only possible way). So I need to know how to produce Protobuf file to the server or how to use files from `format_schemas` in the query (because they included by default and can't be specified as input file in query AFAIK)

Comment: Also, it seems that DBeaver can request data in protobuf, because it's mentioned in official documentation and doesn't complain about `FORMAT` keyword, only about lack of file

Comment: Why do you need DBeaver here? I think  Clickhouse JDBC driver is unable to use format Protobuf. It uses TSV or RowBinary as transport (it depends on a setting). Also Clickhouse java grpc driver uses Protobuf by default.